# Can I pass an list to asyncio.gather?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am trying to start a bunch (one or more) aioserial instances using an `for` and  `asyncio.gather` without success.

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import asyncio
import aioserial
from protocol import contactid, ademco

def main():
    #   Loop  Asyncio
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    centrals = utils.auth()
    #   List of corotines to be executed in paralel
    lst_coro = []
    #   Unpack centrals
    for central in centrals:
        protocol = central['protocol']
        id = central['id']
        name = central['name']
        port = central['port']
        logger = log.create_logging_system(name)
        #   Protocols
        if protocol == 'contactid':
            central = contactid.process
        elif protocol == 'ademco':
            central = ademco.process
        else:
            print(f'Unknown protocol: {central["protocol"]}')
        #  Serial (port ex: ttyUSB0/2400)
        dev = ''.join(['/dev/', *filter(str.isalnum, port.split('/')[0])])
        bps = int(port.split('/')[-1])
        aioserial_instance = aioserial.AioSerial(port=dev, baudrate=bps)
        lst_coro.append(central(aioserial_instance, id, name, logger))
    asyncio.gather(*lst_coro, loop=loop)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

I based this on the asyncio [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#running-tasks-concurrently) example and some answers from stack overflow. But when I try to run it, I just got errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/opt/Serial/serial.py", line 39, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/runners.py", line 37, in run
    raise ValueError("a coroutine was expected, got {!r}".format(main))
ValueError: a coroutine was expected, got None
```

I also tried to use a set instead of a list, but nothing really changed. Is there a better way to start a bunch of parallels corotines when you need to use a loop? Thanks for the attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem isn't with how you call `gather`. It's with how you define `main`. The clue is with the error message

```
ValueError: a coroutine was expected, got None
```

and the last line of code in the traceback before the except is raised

```
asyncio.run(main())
```

`asyncio.run` wants an awaitable. You pass it the return value of `main`, but `main` doesn't return anything. Rather than adding a return value, though, the fix is to change how you define `main`.

```
async def main():
```

This will turn `main` from a regular function to a `coroutine` that can be awaited.

**Edit**

Once you've done this, you'll notice that `gather` doesn't actually seem to do anything. You'll need to await it in order for `main` to wait for everything in `lst_coro` to complete.

```
await asyncio.gather(*lst_coro)
```

Unrelated to your error: you shouldn't need to use `loop` inside `main` at all. `gather`'s `loop` argument was deprecated in 3.8 and will be removed in 3.10. Unless you're using an older version of Python, you can remove it and your call to `asyncio.get_event_loop`.

Comment: Also, the call to `gather()` should itself be awaited: `await asyncio.gather(*lst_coro)`

Comment: @dirn Thank you so much. I still can't believe that I manage to copy an example "wrong".